# Python - Return ID after finding Xpath with Selenium

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm learning xpath and Selenium, and just successfully found the element I am trying to target. I am searching for a element where data-number = 48264

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-number='48264']")
```

The HTML I am pulling from looks like this

```
<li id="pos_4" data-number="48264" class="top-item sellmid">
```

Now I am trying to return the ID "pos_4". I experimented with the below code, but it was totally wrong.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-asin='B01923Y7IG']").id
```

This returned a long float "0.066103113793198-1". Not sure what this is.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-asin='B01923Y7IG']").text
```

The above returned the text inside the div of the li.

Any suggestions on where to look next? I've done a lot of searching, but couldn't find anything helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-number='48264']")

value = ele.get_attribute('id')

print value
```